# Quickest way to get Scaffold code created with C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, scaffolding, skeleton-code

At the start of any project, once you've got your object model there then comes a period of tedium as you crank out the skeleton code required.

Are there any tools that will help me with this task (including unit test skeletons if possible), a bit like the scaffolding feature in Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on the framework stack that you're using:

- [Scaffolding for Monorail + ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/integration/arscaffold.html)
- [ASP.NET MVC + Linq to SQL](http://www.twinforms.com/aspmvc-home.htm)
- [Web forms + dynamic data](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC + Subsonic](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-mvc-adding-updated-for-beta-1/)

Other that than, you could always code your own "scaffolding" using [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) or [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com)

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317566/creating-web-forms-from-a-database-schema)

Comment: I would have linked 'Web forms + dynamic data' to this url instead, as dynamic data was released and that's the official url. http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata