# Automatic mapping from schema to code, database and GUI

Tags: database, user-interface, schema, scaffolding

There are different systems (for different environments, languages) which helps to map schema to data structures in code, in databases, and do automatic glue code between them - ORM, etc.

Is there any common name/abbreviation (like ORM) for systems that in addition do mapping to user interface (in automatic/semi-automatic ways)?

Are there such systems? Of course it would require to select GUI templates for different parts of schema, maybe add a little logic at some places (declarative approach is preferable).

I remember that something similar was available at MS Access - it could automatically create UI Forms from schema or even queries. But I wonder if there are similar systems? (doesn't matter if it web GUI or desktop GUI).

I guess there can be library/framework for do this (Python, C#, Java, C++, PHP, etc), or stand-alone apps like MS Access.

Comment: Downvoter - any comments?

Comment: Not really an SO question (too broad) but sounds like you are after scaffolding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming).  As you haven't stated a language or platform (desktop? web?) then its hard to answer in any more detail

Comment: @will-hart I am looking for any examples for any desktop/web/any_language. If there are many such systems - just show a couple of such examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be talking about scaffolding. Scaffolding is a way to display a very basic user interfaces (GUI) normally based on a database structure.  Depending on the language, framework and implementation it may also provide basic Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD) actions on the GUI.

It is [often](http://www.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=27384) [frowned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735468/why-do-ror-professionals-not-use-scaffolding) [upon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75011/do-experienced-ruby-on-rails-developers-use-scaffolding) for anything other than a very rapid prototype. In fact, 99% of the time you will save more time and be better off learning a framework and doing things "properly".

Having said that, web frameworks seem to be the [kings of scaffolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)#Scaffolding_in_Ruby_on_Rails).

- [Ruby on Rails](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-scaffolding.htm)
- [Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406460/is-there-any-adequate-scaffolding-for-django-a-la-ruby-on-rails)
- [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Scaffolding.html)
- [C#/ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377538/quickest-way-to-get-scaffold-code-created-with-c-asp-net)

My advice would be to pick a well supported framework which favours [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) and follow through some tutorials.  You'll most likely end up in a better place.

Comment: Could you please clarify how Scaffold is related to UI (desktop/web). [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29) is a bit confusing - it just talks about db and code, which make it similar to ORM, but I don't see where is autogenerated UI.

Comment: Thank you. If scaffolding has that meaning, then it is 
"word" I was looking for. Though I am still confused why wiki does not mention GUI.

Comment: This video should give you a bit more of an idea.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USfKteP-eVo  Other than that, good luck!